# convert python pandas dataframe with column names and index names to list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I would like to convert a the dataframe like below (where ix is the index of the dataframe)

| ix | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 0 | 0 |
| Y | 0 | 0 |

to a list of lists like so:

```
[ [ix, A, B], [X, 0, 0], [Y, 0, 0] ]
```

to create a matrix (list of lists) that still contains the dataframe column and index names, A, B and X, Y respectively.

Comment: `[df.columns.to_list()] + df.to_numpy().tolist()` but why?

Comment: I'm was trying to store a list in pandas dataframe and got this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`  so i assumed i should just use a list of lists to complete my task

Comment: @QuangHoang  hello, this doesn't work, i'm also trying to have the index included. The index is not considered a column in pandas, you can only access it using `.index`

Comment: Do df=df.reset_index() before the other command.

Comment: @QuangHoang  my indexes are names that i don't want to reset, basically my indexes are strings. i'm trying to create a 2D mapper like a co-occurrence matrix for words. in the cells i want to store lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `columns` to list and append the `body` list:

```
[df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

[['ix', 'A', 'B'], ['X', 0, 0], ['Y', 0, 0]]
```

Or if you meant to just store this somewhere for reproducibility, you might want to use `to_dict` method:

```
df.to_dict('list')
{'ix': ['X', 'Y'], 'A': [0, 0], 'B': [0, 0]}
```

Comment: hello, this doesn't work, i'm also trying to have the index included. The index is not considered a column in pandas you can only access it using `.index`

Comment: Try `df.reset_index()`

Comment: my indexes are names that i don't want to reset, basically my indexes are strings. i'm trying to create a 2D mapper like a co-occurrence matrix for words. in the cells i want to store lists

Comment: @3awny please ask a new question if you have a different issue. That sounds very far away from what this question has asked.

Answer (score -1):

If all your columns are the same type, I would use `.to_numpy` and then add the columns to the array using something like:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
a = numpy.vstack([df.columns, a])
```

This involves more imports (technically), but you're already importing pandas so numpy isn't much else to bring in.

Comment: As this would convert to an `object` type array, I am not sure of the benefit, might be a better solution if the labels are of same type though